# prove that the map $d:\Bbb R \times\Bbb R \to\Bbb R $ defined by.... Is a metric

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Prove that the map $d:\Bbb R \times\Bbb R \to\Bbb R $ defined by

$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x=y\\
|x|+|y|,&\text{if }x\ne y\,.
\end{cases}$$

is a metric.

If $d(x,y)≥0 $  for all  $x, y \in\Bbb R$.

If $d(x,y) = 0 $ indicates that if $x ≠ y : |x|+|y| = 0$

therefore $0 = x = y $ then $x = y$, if we assume that $x ≠ y$ then

$$\begin{align*}
d(x,y) &= |x|+|y|\\
& \le |x|+|y|+2|z|\\
&= (|x|+|z|) + (|z|+|y|)\\
& = d(x,z) + d(z,y)
\end{align*}$$

Is correct?

Comment: That is correct, except your proof of the last part should also consider the odd special cases: what if $x=y$, and what if $x≠y=z$?

Comment: can you help me complement it? How would the exercise be?

Comment: You just have to do the same calculations, but implementing the fact that the definition of "distance" depends on whether variables agree or not. For example you wrote $|x|+|y| = d(x, y) $ which is almost always correct, but if $x=y$ this is wrong! Anyway, you have done the most difficult cases :)

Comment: You are missing the property $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$. It's trivial, but you should mention it.

Comment: Please help me, I'm confused, I need to finish it.

Answer (score 1):

$d(x,y) = 0 = d(y,x)$ if $x=y$ and if $x \neq y$ then $d(x,y)= |x|+|y| = |y|+|x|=d(y,x)$ too, so symmetry is fulfilled.

If $x \neq y$, then $x \neq 0$ or $y \neq 0$ (they cannot both be $0$ of course) and then $d(x,y) = |x| + |y| >0$. This shows (by contrapositive) that $d(x,y)=0 \to x=y$, and the reverse was already true by definition.

In checking the triangle inequality we can always assume WLOG that all 3 points $x,y,z$ are distinct (as the other cases then follow from the remaining axioms), so

indeed $$d(x,z)=|x|+|z| \le (|x|+|y|) + (|y| + |z|) (\text{ as } |y| \ge 0) = d(x,y)+d(y,z)$$ shows the triangle inequality.

Note that balls around $0$ are the same as in the usual metric, as $d(0,x)=|x|$ for all $x$ and all points $p \neq 0$ are isolated as $B(p, |p|)= \{p\}$ for all such $p$. The metric is often called the post-office metric wrt $0$.